# What statistics should we use for Duck in Mouse Guard?

Tags: mouse-guard

The Mouse Guard world clearly has ducks, but the RPG doesn't include them. **What stats should a Duck have** in Mouse Guard?

Dave Petersen has illustrated [mice interacting with ducks](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Oq2kNZRKShg/StT9u_LVHaI/AAAAAAAABWA/RYiv-y04Qdk/s200/legends.jpg) in Mouse Guard. Heck, Kenzie's character sheet even has the “Duck-wise” skill. Yet there is no mention of ducks in the “Denizens of the Mouse Territories” chapter.

I hope we don't have to wait for the *Water Fowl* splatbook to know the answer to:

- What is the rating for Duck Nature?
- What are the aspects of Duck Nature?
- What weapons, if any, do Ducks have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To tide our group over until there's an official answer, I've used:

- Duck Nature: **6 (Flying, Eating Stuff, Swimming)**
- Duck Weapons: none

Comment: Eff official, that looks great to me.

Comment: Works for me. Looks about right.

Comment: Think you should tick your own answer here.

Answer (score 3):

There was a small expansion booklet (New Rules, New Missions) with rules for some of the new things that had appeared in the comics, including mounts! In brief, when mounted, a mouse uses the size and Natures of the mount instead of mouse Nature and Natural Order position, and may opt to use the mount's weapon instead of its own.

In light of that, here's a duck that presents some interesting mount options. (Not the pictured duck, which I presume is a non-diving mallard, but a redhead, which also summers in and around <s>Michigan</s> the Territories.)

- **Duck Nature 6** (Flying, Swimming, Diving)
- **Duck Weapons** - Deep Dive: +2D to maneuver, +1s to successful Feint

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer looks fine, though you might give them a beak weapon, depending on what you were using them for.  Luke didn't include any rules for mice riding animals in the RPG, even the rabbits they're shown riding at the end of the Winter chapter, partially because those comics hadn't come out yet when the RPG was published.

Comment: Since the Goose doesn't have a beak weapon, I don't think the Duck gets one :-)